# How to filter DataTables for each value in a specific column?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable, filtering

I have a DataTable and the data is showing fine. Here is an example:

| Name | Month | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Allison | June 2021 | 5 |
| Allison | July 2021 | 7 |
| Allison | August 2021 | 3 |
| Benjamin | June 2021 | 10 |
| Benjamin | July 2021 | 4 |
| ..... | ..... | .... |

For each same Name, I want to do the following:

For each same Name in the table, Example "Allison" >> For each score >> If score=>5 for last consecutive two months, then show rows of Allison for the last two months.

Comment: Can you please provide some code? I will be more than happy to help

Comment: Look at this example. I think this is what you are searching for: https://datatables.net/extensions/searchpanes/examples/customFiltering/customOptionConditions.html

Answer (score 1):

There could be multiple ways:-

1. Before binding the result you can manipulate data and remove the records from your object.
2. After showing the result you have to write a custom function that starts from the top row to the end and check your condition and take action.

**Steps to perform for your custom method are:**

- Loop around for all records in table
- pick n record
- check conditions

  ```
  if score of n-1 and n-2 record are >=5 
  AND 
  if n(name),n-1(name),n-2(name) records all are the same 
  AND
  if val(n-1(month)) == val(n-2(month))-1
  THEN 
  hide current(n) row
  ```